# How to access Wpf application from a browser?

Tags: wpf

I have a WPF application (Not Wpf Browser appliction) and i want accesss my wpf aplication from browser. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

We call that [Silverlight](http://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/) my friend

Comment: How do i convert my standalone wpf application to XBAP? i have gone through many articles but i coudn't find any solution